# Empty td tags appear for no reason

Tags: html, razor

I have a rather unusual problem. I have a view structure which rellies on a table with the following format:

```
<table class="smartTable">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Case_Status, new { @id = "caseStatus", @Value = "In Progress", @readonly = "true", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <tr>
        <td width="33.33%">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Job_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Job_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            <br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <td>
        <td width="33.33%">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Package_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Package_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            <br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Package_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <td>
        <td width="33.33%">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Server_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Server_Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SrvNames, "Pick an option")
                            <br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Server_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have several such tables (and I don't want to change the format). The problem is, when my view loads it has empty `<td>` tags in between the three `<td>` that I already put in the code. It happens to only two of the tables and idk why.

Does somebody have any idea what causes such strange behaviour?

PS: A previous version of my site doesn't have this problem. I have no jQuery to mess with the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at is in your last td inside div **close SelectListItem** tag like this

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Server_Name, (IEnumerable)ViewBag.SrvNames, "Pick an option")

                            
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Server_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Comment: I can't really get what you're trying to say. The only difference I see is the lack of <SelectListItem> and the no <br /> tag. Which one is it? And what to do if I can't delete them?

Comment: You just need to end the SelectListItem tag             <div class="dropdown">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Server_Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SrvNames, "Pick an option")
       </SelectListItem>
                            <br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Server_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

Comment: But SelectListItem is not a tag, it is encapsulated in a C# logic (@ refers to C#). It is a part of a cast to a certain C# type and does not have to comply to html structure.

Comment: ok so you close the tag itself like this <div class="dropdown">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Server_Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem/>)ViewBag.SrvNames, "Pick an option")
       
                            <br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Server_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>